# Yii clean url with id and name

Tags: php, yii, seo

I want my url's to have the following patter:

```
http://example.com/controller/view_id/title_name, like SO:

http://stackoverflow.com/question/1/title
```

Config.php:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'appendParams' => true,
        'rules'=>array(
            'user/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>'=>array('user/view', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
            '<controller>/<id:\d+>/<name:.*?>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    )
```

UserController:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
   $this->render('view', array(
     'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
   ));
}
```

I am trying to redirect `user/view/1` to `user/1/my_username`
The url `user/1/username` is redirecting me to `Error 400 invalid request`. 
What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using url http://[yourhost]/user/1/username, Then [.htaccess](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/427/htaccess-seo-friendly-url/) file is necessary. Other wise you can always check through http://[yourhost]/index.php/user/1/username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your user and question  controller has `action view`.Here view should be the name of action.

Try this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'appendParams' => true,
     'caseSensitive'=>false,//use case sensitivity here 
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller>/<view_id:\d+>/<title_name:[\w -\.]+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
)
```

If your Url is like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/question/1/title
```

When you hit this url.In main.php this line will read your url.

```
'<controller>/<view_id:\d+>/<title_name:[\w -\.]+>'=>'<controller>/view',
//view_id and title_name you can change there name.
```

It will work like this:

```
 <controller>=question
 <view_id:\d+>=1
 <title_name:[\w -\.]+>=title
```

and you will redirect to `<controller>`'s  `function actionView()` automatically.You can get the url values like this `$_GET['view_id']` AND `$_GET['title_name']` in actionView().

You have to Do this:

```
public function actionView() 
{ 
   $this->render('view', array( 'model' => $this->loadModel($_GET['view_id']))); 
 }
```

Comment: I have change my answer you can check it there.If error occurred.Then tell me.

Comment: Provide your controller code and the url You are using

Comment: Why are you passing $id in it? What is your URL?

Comment: Try this public function actionView()
{
   $this->render('view', array(
     'model' => $this->loadModel($_GET['view_id']),
   ));
}

Comment: Yes, but i want to know if there is a problem to SEO if there are two routes pointing to the same page.

Comment: No, there will be no problem in that.

Comment: Actually it is a problem. Read here how to get around this: http://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization